# Bathtub drain issue

Tags: plumbing

I have replaced the trip lever on my bathtub drain but it will not stay completely down when draining. I am able to remove the mechanism (including the weight at the bottom) but can't seem to get the tub to drain without holding the lever down manually. What is the correct setting for the the trip lever attachment---there are several holes to choose from? Is there something else I should be doing?

Answer (score 1):

That "weight" you refer to is the stopper. If the trip lever won't stay down, you may need to replace it. The spring is supposed to hold it in the down position, which actually holds the stopper **up**. Even if you adjusted the lever attachment to hold the stopper higher up, if the lever will not maintain that position then the stopper will drop down and partially (or completely) block the drain.